# Extracting all data from a specific column in a nested QStandardItemModel

Tags: c++, qt, qstandarditemmodel

I have a `QStandardItemModel` which i am passing through view to display it inside a `QTreeView`. My model contains 2 columns working like Key and Value pairs. First column, contains a fix template of Keys and the second column contains their corresponding values. My sample tree looks somewhat like this:

```
Item | Attributes
Name   Tomato
 |-Type Fruit
 |-Color Red
Name ...
 |-Type ...
```

As i said my template on the first column stays the same but the values in the second column are inputs from the user.

**What do i want:**

I want to traverse (recursively) through the model, grabbing all the values from the `Attributes` column and write it to a file

**What did i do so far:**

```
void Writer::writeToYaml(const std::shared_ptr<QStandardItemModel>& model, 
                               const QString& filePath)                 
{

    for(int r = 0; r < model->rowCount(); ++r)
    {
        QModelIndex index = model->index(r, 1);
        QVariant data = model->data(index);
        qDebug() << data;

        if(model->hasChildren(index))
        {
            writeToYaml(model, filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

When i run my code the `qDebug()` only outputs `Tomato` all the time. 
I believe the loop itself terminates at the root node resulting in only the first value. Is it possible to recursively extract all the items from a specific column in a nested model?

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing it from top of my head, so you may have to tweak it a bit, but it should work. You need to to address lower level items with parent indices.

But I'm not sure your model is correct, because the code you provided should not print 'tomato', but should create an infinite loop, because once you recursively call `writeToYaml`, you iterate over top-level items again. That means `model->hasChildren(index)` is most likely never true in your case...

```
void Writer::writeToYaml(const std::shared_ptr<QAbstractItemModel>& model, const QString& filePath)                 
{

    std::stack<QModelIndex> indices;

    for (int = model->rowCount() - 1; r >= 0; --r) // iterate from last to first as you put items on a stack
    {
        indices.push(model->index(r, 1));
    }

    while (!indices.empty())
    {
        auto index = indices.top();
        indices.pop();

        QVariant data = model->data(index);
        qDebug() << data;

        if (model->hasChildren(index))
        {
            for (int r = model->rowCount(index) -1 ; r >= 0; --r)
//                                       ^^^^^ note this, this iterates over all children of item on given index
            {
                indices.push(model->index(r, 1, index));
//                                              ^^^^^ this is the parent index that identifies the item in tree hierarchy
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right! A call to `writeToYaml` should create an infinite loop whenever it is true. But the index i am getting is from second column which has no children. I used it to show if it is possible to grab items recursively. Let me try your code.

Comment: thank you for the approach! I have fixed some typos and changed a brief logic in your code to get the values for parent nodes as well. I believe it can be made much cleaner but for now it works for me. Moreover, the order of the extraction is not important in my case.
Since you came up with this approach i will mark it as an answer.